# Set field value with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field

I'm working with one project which is not opensource and I need to modify one or more its classes.

In one class is following collection:

```
private Map<Integer, TTP> ttp = new HashMap<>();
```

All what I need to do is use reflection and use concurrenthashmap here.
I've tried following code but it doesnt work.

```
Field f = ..getClass().getDeclaredField("ttp");
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(null, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```

Comment: What does it mean: but it doesnt work? On which object do you call `.getClass().getDeclaredField("ttp")`

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Hope this is something what you are trying to do :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {

    private Map ttp = new HashMap(); 

    public  void test() {
        Field declaredField =  null;
        try {

            declaredField = Test.class.getDeclaredField("ttp");
            boolean accessible = declaredField.isAccessible();

            declaredField.setAccessible(true);

            ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object> concHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>();
            concHashMap.put("key1", "value1");
            declaredField.set(this, concHashMap);
            Object value = ttp.get("key1");

            System.out.println(value);

            declaredField.setAccessible(accessible);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException 
                | SecurityException
                | IllegalArgumentException 
                | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test(); 
    }
}
```

*It prints :*

```
value1
```

Comment: I looking for some code for copy all field values from a class to another. But the fields are not just native types.
It's possible?

Comment: @Krismorte *"fields are not just native types"* means? for instance?

Comment: @Krismorte Late as @#$%, but possible - yes. Sounds like you're looking for a "bean to bean mapper" one example you may be interested in is https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/

Comment: @Visruth Means fields like "HisOwnClass" rather than "int" or "Integer" etc.

Answer (score 24):

It's worth reading [Oracle Java Tutorial - Getting and Setting Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html)

[Field#set(Object object, Object value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) sets the field represented by this `Field` object on the **specified object** argument to the specified new value.

It should be like this

```
f.set(objectOfTheClass, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```

You can't set any value in `null` Object If tried then it will result in `NullPointerException`

---

**Note:** Setting a field's value via reflection has a certain amount of *performance overhead* because various operations must occur such as validating access permissions. From the runtime's point of view, the effects are the same, and the operation is as atomic as if the value was changed in the class code directly.

Answer (score 15):

The method below sets a field on your object even if the field is in a superclass

```
/**
 * Sets a field value on a given object
 *
 * @param targetObject the object to set the field value on
 * @param fieldName    exact name of the field
 * @param fieldValue   value to set on the field
 * @return true if the value was successfully set, false otherwise
 */
public static boolean setField(Object targetObject, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
    Field field;
    try {
        field = targetObject.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        field = null;
    }
    Class superClass = targetObject.getClass().getSuperclass();
    while (field == null && superClass != null) {
        try {
            field = superClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
        }
    }
    if (field == null) {
        return false;
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        field.set(targetObject, fieldValue);
        return true;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
//Your class instance
Publication publication = new Publication();

//Get class with full path(with package name)
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.example.publication.models.Publication");

//Get method
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("setTitle", String.class);

//set value
method.invoke (publication,  "Value to want to set here...");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
static class Student {
    private int age;
    private int number;

    public Student(int age, int number) {
        this.age = age;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Student() {
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Student student1=new Student();
   // Class g=student1.getClass();
    Field[]fields=student1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    Field age=student1.getClass().getDeclaredField("age");
    age.setAccessible(true);
    age.setInt(student1,13);
    Field number=student1.getClass().getDeclaredField("number");
    number.setAccessible(true);
    number.setInt(student1,936);

    for (Field f:fields
         ) {
        f.setAccessible(true);

        System.out.println(f.getName()+" "+f.getInt(student1));

    }
}
```

}