# transform fields map to class instance

Tags: java, android, list, dictionary, transformation

Let's say I have simple `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("field1","value1");
map.put("field2", "value2");
```

I also have simple java class:

```
class SimpleClass {
 public String field1;
 public String field2;
}
```

What is simplest and most elegant way to create `SimpleClass` instance with corresponding fields/values taken from map? In this case, resulting `SimpleClass` instance should get `field1` value 'value1`and`field2`value`value2`.

`SimpleClass` is already defined, now we need to find matching keys in map, if match found, it's value should be assigned to corresponding class field.

In my real application, I will get list of maps and I need to transform it into `List<SimpleClass>`. Map can contain additional keys, that need to be ommited (if no matching class field is available).

Can I use (for example) Guava to make transoformation like this? I'm on Android so java streams can't be used so far.

[edit]

My attempt:

```
 private SimpleClass mapToObject(Map<String, String> map)
    {
        SimpleClass result = new SimpleClass();

        for(Field f: result.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        {
            try
            {
                f.setAccessible(true);
                f.set(result,map.get(f.getName()));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("error", e.toString());
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Let's say you have written some code. You also have tried to execute it. What is the simplest and most elegant way you could demonstrate that you've actually attempted something?

Comment: Your comment is not very useful

Comment: Neither is your question, in its current state.

Comment: Really? Why are you saying that?

Comment: The absolute minimum that we expect is that you have at least attempted to solve the problem yourself. Why should we put in effort if you haven't? Maybe you have attempted something, but nothing about your questions suggests that you have.

Comment: The only way I think about is to use reflection to list class fields and construct class instance in loop, which is pretty bad solution in my opinion.

Comment: Mapping strings to field names (or method names, in the case of setters) is always going to involve reflection. Java is not a dynamic language, reflection is the only way to accomplish things like this.

Comment: You could loop your map, and [set the field value using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094871/set-field-value-with-reflection)

Comment: My attempt added, but I feel this is not best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use ObjectMapper ,

```
SimpleClass  simpleClass = objectMapper.convertValue(map, SimpleClass.class);
```

Comment: Do you mean Jackson ObjectMapper?

Comment: Yes , com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper