# Spring Data find entity by its fields with reflection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Having a lot of duplicate code in a lot of service classes, I decided to move it to a base service class and then re-use it.

```
public class BaseService<ENTITY, ID> {

@Autowired
private BaseDao<ENTITY, ID> baseDao;

protected boolean isExist(ENTITY e) {
    Map<Field, Object> allValues = ReflectUtils.getAllValues(e);
    //...

}

}
```

In `isExist(ENTITY e)` method I'd like to call a baseDao method to find an entity (at the runtime it has to know which exact entity) and pass `allValues` to it. Basically, I'd like to know if it's possible to do smth like this with Spring Data:

```
public interface BaseDao<ENTITY, ID> extends JpaRepository<ENTITY, ID> {

Optional<ENTITY> findByFields(Map<Field, Object> allValues);
}
```

Comment: I believe it's not possible with `Map` parameter. But it should be doable by combining your reflective approach to create examples and using the [Query by Example API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example).  A guide about it - [Spring Data JPA Query by Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example).

Comment: @Chaosfire thx. That's exactly what I need. Can I accept your answer?

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that by providing `Map` parameter to a repository method, but it's possible by combining the reflective approach with spring's [Query By Example API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example). Simplified example:

```
public <Entity> Optional<Entity> findByFields(Map<Field, Object> allValues) throws IllegalAccessException {
  Entity entity = create an instance;
  for (Map.Entry<Field, Object> entry : allValues.entrySet()) {
    //allow access to the field
    entry.getKey().set(entity, entry.getValue());
    //restore access to previous state
  }
  Example<Entity> example = Example.of(entity);
  return queryByExampleExecutor.findOne(example);
}
```

Probably helpful questions:

1. [Set field value with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094871/set-field-value-with-reflection)
2. [Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626825/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example)